# TypeScript Merged Declaration Composition Doesn't Work If Target Class Is Extended

Tags: node.js, typescript, mixins, composition, es6-class

I need to take a TypeScript `class` that has been extended and compose it with a few others. I found this article (and a few others like it) showing a pattern that I thought I would be able to use:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Here is an illustration of my predicament using the example code from the above article as a minimal repro.

**working.test.ts** (original)

```js
// Each mixin is a traditional ES class
class Jumpable {
  jump() {}
}

class Duckable {
  duck() {}
}

// Including the base
class Sprite {
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
}

// Then you create an interface which merges
// the expected mixins with the same name as your base
interface Sprite extends Jumpable, Duckable {}
// Apply the mixins into the base class via
// the JS at runtime
applyMixins(Sprite, [Jumpable, Duckable]);

let player = new Sprite();
player.jump();
console.log(player.x, player.y);

// This can live anywhere in your codebase:
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, constructors: any[]) {
  constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
        derivedCtor.prototype,
        name,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name)
      );
    });
  });
}
```

The above code runs fine, however if we add another intermediary class, say `Fairy` and then have `Sprite` extend that, we will run into an error:

**broken.test.ts**

```js
// Each mixin is a traditional ES class
class Jumpable {
  jump() {}
}

class Duckable {
  duck() {}
}

class Fairy {
  z = "z"
}

// Including the base
class Sprite extends Fairy {
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
}

// Then you create an interface which merges
// the expected mixins with the same name as your base
interface Sprite extends Jumpable, Duckable {}
// Apply the mixins into the base class via
// the JS at runtime
applyMixins(Sprite, [Jumpable, Duckable]);

let player = new Sprite();
player.jump();
console.log(player.x, player.y);

// This can live anywhere in your codebase:
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, constructors: any[]) {
  constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
        derivedCtor.prototype,
        name,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name)
      );
    });
  });
}
```

This will throw the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

The specific line that is throwing the error is the instantiation of the Sprite class:

```js
let player = new Sprite();
```

According to every other post about that error that I've seen, the solution was to call the class with the `new` keyword... but that's already happening...

I'm very lost on why this is happening, it feels like something hidden away internally in TypeScript is breaking...

**EDIT**
It turns out these files only throw errors when I run them with Jest, running it with `ts-node` or in TypeScript playground works.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in [the playground](https://shorturl.at/bgxS1). Is there anything else in your code that could be causing this to break?

Comment: @cherryblossom thank you for the attempt to repro, I can confirm this does work as expected in playground. I then ran my my file locally with `ts-node` at that worked as well, the error persists when I run these test files with Jest however, so it seems that may be where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be Jest and the configuration in my repo for it. I was/am in the middle of transitioning a JS repo to TypeScript and as such, Jest was not yet properly set up for TypeScript.

Here's how I fixed it:

1. Delete the old `jest.config.js` and `babel.config.js` as well as removing the (now) unnecessary `babel`, `babel-jest` and misc other babel plugins from dependencies.
2. Add `ts-jest` and `@types/jest` to `devDependencies`.
3. Use ts-jest to create a new jest config via `yarn ts-jest config:init`
4. Profit!

The main source of my confusion was really that the error message led me to an issue on the `jest` GH repo where (almost) all the solutions were actually for plain JS, while I was trying to apply them to TS.